# Disable all dates in datetime range picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

I am using a datetime range picker as given [here](https://www.daterangepicker.com/#example2). In some scenarios, I need only start-time and end-time dropdowns. Is it possible to disable all dates shown in the calendar or hide the calendar? I also want to remove the label displayed before the "Cancel" and "Apply" buttons. Does anyone know how to do this?

[image]

Comment: if you use ```ranges``` option, you can set ```alwaysShowCalendars``` option to false

Comment: Thanks, @scr2em. But even after setting ```alwaysShowCalendars``` option to false, if I select the "custom Range" option from the dropdown, I can still see the calendar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [official doc](https://www.daterangepicker.com/#example2)

autoApply: (true/false) Hide the apply and cancel buttons, and automatically apply a new date range as soon as two dates are clicked.

show.daterangepicker: Triggered when the picker is shown

```
$('#daterangepicker').daterangepicker({
    "autoApply": true,
}).on('show.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {
    picker.container.find(".calendar-table").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using JQuery to hide the calendar but not sure whether this is the right way to do it.

```
# Hide Calendar
$(".calendar-table").hide();

# Hide label that is displayed before "Cancel" and "Apply" buttons.
$(".drp-selected").hide();
```